# how to make POST method works for two different forms on same page with flask?

Tags: python, flask

how to make POST method works for two different forms on same page with flask ?

Here's my code from main `__int__.py` file for flask / python

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/login/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    error = None
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['email'] != '1' or \
                request.form['password'] != '1':
            flash('Invalid Credentials')
        else:
            flash('You were successfully logged in')
            return redirect(url_for('dashborad'))
    return render_template('login.html', error=error)


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/register/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            email = request.form['email1']
            name = request.form['name1']
            password = request.form['password1']

            cur, db = connection()
            x = cur.execute(" SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = (%s)" ,[escape(email)])

            if int(x) > 0:
                flash ("email already used ")
                return render_template ("register.html")
            else:
                cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (first_name, email, password) VALUES (%s, %s, %s);" ,(escape(name), escape(email), escape(password) ))

                db.commit()
        return render_template ("register.html")
```

right now python is reading POST method for first @app.route login form only

is there any easy way to get such line in python ?

```
if request.method == 'POST' for form 1
```

and

```
 if request.method == 'POST' for form 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the way to do that using Ajax request in JavaScript for each form on the same page

> Example:-

HTML form

```
<form onsubmit="formSumbit()">
  email: <input id="email" type="text">
  password: <input id="password" type="password">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

JavaScript POST request function for each form it will look something like this

```
function formSumbit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    fetch("http://yourwebsite.com/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        body: JSON.stringify({ email: document.getElementById('email').value, password: document.getElementById('password').value })
    }).then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return res.json();
    }).then((data) => {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

And to use two POST route handlers for each form in Flask or pass extra parameter called `'form1'` or `'form2'` and check for the parameter in Flask route handler.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like the starting page of [LinkedIn](https://www.linkedin.com/)

To achieve that in Flask create the HTML template as :

```html
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Save">
<input type="submit" name="btn" value="Cancel">
```

and then you can validate by:

```
if request.form["btn"]=="Save":
    if request.method== 'POST':
        doSomething()
```

This solution might work

Comment: thank you for your answer , but it gave this error 
400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: [use this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21949452/wtforms-two-forms-on-the-same-page)

Comment: i think i have to use WTForms after all
i have a project to use as minimum as possible of frameworks 

thanks again buddy

Comment: yes I guess you have to.Flask has an easy API for that [link](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)